# Is there a way to simulate a bash shell inside the crontab file?

Tags: bash, cron

I noticed when I tried to use bash's 'date' inside a command, I could not, when I tried to pick up a file that varies by date.

Comment: You could try to use `/bin/bash -c 'command'` to start the command in a bash session. Remember to escape all single quotes in the command with a backslash.

Comment: What command have you tried exactly?

Comment: You may want to tell your crontab to run a bash script instead... it solves the problems you're trying to fix.

Comment: ... `mutt -F /path/to/.muttrc -s subject <addr> > /path/to/msg.txt -a /path/to/$(date +'%y%m%d-%H%M')_log.txt` When I try this, I get an error about an unterminated quoted string

Comment: @Thomas W. -- that's what I've done for now, but crontab acts weird with bash files I've seen at least once, so I was hoping to fit a fairly simple bash command into the crontab file

Comment: @cfye14 Acts weird how?

Comment: I remember there being an issue with root vs user. That may not apply here given the -F option. Or maybe something with a path variable.

Comment: Use userspace crontab then if you need it to run as the user and not root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `cron` treats `%` as newlines. From `man 5 crontab`:

```
Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (\), 
will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first %  will  be
sent to the command as standard input.
```

To solve that you need to escape the `%` by `\%`.

Alternately if you want to run the command from a `bash` script, make the script executable and put it e.g. like below from `crontab -e`:

```
05 06 * * * /path/to/script.sh
```

Make the shebang of the script as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Now the `bash` script will be run everyday at 6:05 AM.

Comment: This solved my problem. Re: the script approach, it looks like I need `bash /path/to ...` in the `crontab -e`, no?

Comment: @cfye14 we are using the shebang to indicate that the script should be interpreted by `bash`, so no need for `bash /path/to/script.sh`

Comment: it only works for me if I add `bash` in front of the path in `crontab -e`. Otherwise, I get a 'permission denied.'

Comment: @cfye14 Make the script executable & add `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as the first line of the script..

Comment: ok gotcha, sorted.