# Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution

Tags: bash, cron

I scheduled following cron job:

```
root@alexus:~# crontab -l | grep ^\@hourly
@hourly     OUT=`/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_disk --include-type=ext4 --warning=10% --critical=5%` ; if [ $? != 0 ] ; then echo $OUT ; fi
root@alexus:~# OUT=`/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_disk --include-type=ext4 --warning=10% --critical=5%` ; if [ $? != 0 ] ; then echo $OUT ; fi
root@alexus:~# cat /etc/issue.net 
Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
root@alexus:~#
```

and even though I'm able to run *EXACTLY* same one liner within shell, whenever job gets executed via cron, I get following email:

> Subject: Cron  OUT=`/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_disk
>   --include-type=ext4 --warning=10 /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution

per subject line, it seems like everything after `%` sign is missing.

How do I properly escape it without breaking my script?

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/a/637378/158442

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to check your `crontab(5)` man page. Some implementations of cron will use `%` as a **newline** in the command field, so you can pass data to the command on stdin

```
* * * * * >$HOME/cron.cat.out cat%hello%world
```

Then "cron.cat.out" contains 2 lines:

```
hello
world
```

You'll need

- to escape your percent signs
- I recommend using `$()` instead of backticks
- Quote the `"$OUT"` -- [always quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells) unless you need the specific side-effects of leaving them unquoted.

```
@hourly     OUT=$(/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_disk --include-type=ext4 --warning=10\% --critical=5\%) || echo "$OUT"
# ...................................................................................^..............^
```